# How can I modify my code so that the size of the box shadow is same as the image size in every size of the webpage

Tags: css

[image: when the webpage is set to 67% zoom]

above is the webpage when is set to 67% zoom
css code
how to set so that the box shadow can have the size as the image when i zoom into every different size of the webpage

```
.home__perfill{
    position: relative;
    justify-self: center;
   }

.profile_image{
    width: 350px;
    height: 425px;
}

.profile_img {
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
    display: block;
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
 }


.home__shadow{
    width:90%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    position: absolute;
    top:1rem;
    left: 1.75rem;
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

html code

```
    <div class="home__perfill">
        <div class="profile_image">
            <img src="./assets/profileImg.jpeg" alt="Ming Yang profile picture" class="profile_img"/>
            <div class="home__shadow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: when the zoom in webpage is 90%]/8Ffql.jpg
above is the image when the webpage is set to 90% zoom

Answer (score 2):

Setting your box shadow width and height to 90% causes it to be dynamic when the page changes size. To fix this, set your `.home__shadow` width and height to pixels instead of percentage.

New `.home__shadow` code, assuming you want the box shadow to be the same size as the image:

```css
.home__shadow {
    width: 350px; // CHANGED
    height: 425px; // CHANGED
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    left: 1.75rem;
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: wow, thx a lot , it works